# Import "msgraph.core" could not be resolved - Help me search my OneDrive for Duplicates M365 Home Edition

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to check my home edition of OneDrive for duplicate files.
On https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
I can see results for simple queries after giving consent. Yay?

But constantly getting this error in VS Code on Windows 11, Python v3.11:

> **"Import "msgraph.core" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports"**

I am not in any conda environment.
Installed it uninstalled then did this:

```
PS C:\Users\Test> pip show msgraph-core     
>>
**Name: msgraph-core
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Core component of the Microsoft Graph Python SDK
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: Microsoft <graphtooling+python@microsoft.com>
License: MIT License**
.....blah blahc blah
Required-by: msgraph-sdk
```

*I have not filled out the AZ client ID (because it is a home version, I can't find that..yet)*
but should it still be giving me the msgraph.core error - it seems it can't find it?

Code:

```
from msgraph.core import GraphClient
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
import hashlib

# Azure app registration details
CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'  # Replace with your Azure AD client ID

# Scopes required by the app
SCOPES = ['Files.ReadWrite.All']  # Scope for OneDrive access

# Authentication with Interactive Browser Credential
credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential(client_id=CLIENT_ID)
graph_client = GraphClient(credential=credential, scopes=SCOPES)

# Create an empty dictionary to store the hashes and file names
hashes = {}

# Function to process files and find duplicates in a folder
def process_files(folder_id):
    request_url = f'me/drive/items/{folder_id}/children'
    drive_items = graph_client.get(request_url).json()

    for item in drive_items['value']:
        # Check if the item is a file
        if 'file' in item:
            # Get the file content
            file_content = graph_client.get(item['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl']).content

            # Create a hash object using md5
            hash_obj = hashlib.md5()
            hash_obj.update(file_content)
            hash_digest = hash_obj.hexdigest()

            if hash_digest in hashes:
                print(f"{item['name']} is a duplicate of {hashes[hash_digest]}")
            else:
                hashes[hash_digest] = item['name']
        elif 'folder' in item:
            # If the item is a folder, process its contents
            process_files(item['id'])

# Start processing from the root folder
root_folder = graph_client.get('me/drive/root').json()
process_files(root_folder['id'])
```

I was expecting **NOT** to get:

> "Import "msgraph.core" could not be resolved"

and perhaps some code error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when upgrading to the newly released 1.0.0.
Change your import to `msgraph_core`. But be aware that `GraphClient` is no longer available.
You will have to downgrade your installation to **0.2.2** if you want to use that import and class.
See [the package history](https://pypi.org/project/msgraph-core/0.2.2/#history) for more information.

In addition, check out [this comment](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core/issues/226) by the devs which encourages to use the [SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python) instead.
There is also a [migiration guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/blob/main/UPGRADING.md) which lists your case.

Comment: Yes that fixed the error.  Of course I have to fix m script to find those duplicates online!  THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 0):

This means module `msgraph.core` was not found in your current Python interpreter.

1. You can try to use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the python interpreter which you installed this module.
2. If you just want to disable this warning. You could add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```json
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none"
}
```

Comment: Thank for for responding.  I have two interpreters same error for both.  Initially this line "from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential" had the error, but when I did the pip install, it worked.  They were installed with the same interpreter.  Or should I try with a new environment.